# Async load image to custom UITableViewCell partially working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, uitableview

My images dont load into the imageview until you scroll the cell off the table and back on, or go to another view and come back to the the view (redraws the cell).

How do I make them load in correctly?

/////////

My viewDidLoad has this in it:

```
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        self.getBusinesses()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        }
    }
```

I call the function download the image here in the .getBusinesses function called in viewDidLoad:

```
func getBusinesses() -> Array<Business> {

    var businessList = Array<Business>()
    //let id  = 1
    let url = URL(string: "**example**")!
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
    var isnil = false

    if data == nil{
        isnil = true
    }
    print("is nill is \(isnil)")


    if(data == nil){
        print("network error")
        businessList = []
        return businessList
    }
    else{
        values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    }

    let json = JSON(values)

    var i = 0;
    for (key, values) in json {

        var businessReceived = json[key]
        let newBusiness = Business(id: "18", forename: "", surname: "", email: "", password: "", business: true, level: 1, messageGroups: [], problems: [])

        newBusiness.name = businessReceived["name"].stringValue
        newBusiness.description = businessReceived["description"].stringValue
        newBusiness.rating = Int(businessReceived["rating"].doubleValue)
        newBusiness.category = businessReceived["category"].intValue
        newBusiness.distance =  Double(arc4random_uniform(198) + 1)
        newBusiness.image_url  = businessReceived["image"].stringValue
        newBusiness.url  = businessReceived["url"].stringValue
        newBusiness.phone  = businessReceived["phone"].stringValue
        newBusiness.postcode  = businessReceived["postcode"].stringValue
        newBusiness.email = businessReceived["email"].stringValue
        newBusiness.id = businessReceived["user_id"].stringValue

        if(newBusiness.image_url  == ""){
            newBusiness.getImage()

        }
        else{
            newBusiness.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NoImage")
        }


        if(businessReceived["report"].intValue !=  1){
            businessList.append(newBusiness)

        }
    }

    businesses = businessList

    print(businesses.count)
    holdBusinesses = businessList
    return businessList

}
```

Here in the business object i have this method to download the image from the url and store it in the business object's image property:

```
 func getImage(){

    if(self.image_url != ""){

        print("runs imageeee")
        var storage = FIRStorage.storage()

        // This is equivalent to creating the full reference
        let storagePath = "http://firebasestorage.googleapis.com\(self.image_url)"
        var storageRef = storage.reference(forURL: storagePath)




        // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
        storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {
                // Data for "images/island.jpg" is returned
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                print("returned image")
            }
        }


    }
    else{

        self.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "NoImage")

    }

}
```

I then output it in the tableview here:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell  = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for : indexPath) as! BusinessesViewCell


            cell.businessImage.image = businesses[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].image


            //.............  

     return cell
}
```

Comment: it would be good if you use SDwebImage

Comment: but more relevant if you remember that the download is asynchronous - so there's no data available when you call tableView.reloadData() in viewDidLoad - have a look at delegate calls, and use them to trigger the view to reload the tableView only when the data is available

Comment: sounds interesting, if it loaded the tableview when the images were downloaded that would be perfect! do you have any experience in this @Russell

Comment: Where do you populate the array businesses[] with the returned image?    downloadImage() just appears to set a single value.  Also - If you're doing everything in the same class, it's even simpler than using delegates - just make sure that you refresh the tableView from within the completion handler of your download

Comment: In getBusinesses function called in viewdidload, will amend original code now for you to see @Russell

Comment: OK - as you get each new image 'newBusiness.image = XX', you can reload each new row in the table, but you may have to maintain an index count in the JSON loop

Comment: can you show where you call downloadImage()

Comment: newBusiness.image  = XX never occurs in this instance, as newBusiness.getImage() calls the method on the business object to download and put the image download into self.image, which is what is put in the imageview in the cellForRow function, hope this clears that up. @Russell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
```

should become

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
    }
```

Inside

```
    storageRef.data(withMaxSize: 30 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
```

EDIT: My initial thought was the download logic was inside the cell, now I know its not.

you either need to call reloadData() on the tableView each time you get to

```
         self.image = UIImage(data: data!)!
```

or better yet find out which index you just updated, then called

```
  tableView.reloadRows:[IndexPath]
```

Comment: how would you suggest going about either of these methods as          self.image = UIImage(data: data!)! is in a method in the object so cant reload data from there and also because the second way, the tableview is oringaly loaded from when i have all the data?  @SeanLintern88

Comment: apologies should have said getImage(), copied the wrong function, but they are identical in all but name so changed my code on here. As you can see now you know the right name, it is called in getBusinesses(), apologies! @SeanLintern88

Comment: I would move the getImage into the cell.... then give the cell the path and then download it.

Comment: sorry @SeanLintern88 I'm not following exactly what you mean by that

Comment: put the getImage() func into the cell, then when you configure the cell with the path, get the image

Comment: "configure the cell with the path, get the image –" - what does this mean? Sorry that was what confused me before too haha @SeanLintern88

Comment: instead of giving your cell an image give it a string, which is the path to the image, then move getImage() into cell

Comment: "instead of giving your cell an image give it a string, which is the path to the image, then move getImage() into cell " <- worked! Thanks @SeanLintern88

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cell.businessImage.setNeedsLayout()
```